# spring boot - how can import resource properties file?

Tags: spring-boot, properties

I have multiple resource files.

src/main/resources/application.properties
src/main/resources-dev/application.properties

```xml
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>mask/**</include>
                    <include>message/**</include>
                    <include>sql/**</include>
                    <include>log4j*.*</include>
                    <include>mail-templates/**</include>
                    <include>*.txt</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources-${env}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

---

I want to separate test resource file "src/test/resource-dev/application.properties", and import "main/*/application.properties".

"test/*/application.properties" file has the other items which "src/main/resources*/application.properties" files don't have, like tester account information.

```
src/main/resources\*/application.properties  // build properties like jdbc, securty info etc
src/test/resource-dev/application.properties // tester account
```

so. I add property on "src/test/resource-dev/application.properties" like below, but it doesn't work.

```
spring.config.import = application.properties
```

```
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/main/resources-${env}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources-${env}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
```

how can i add pom.xml and properties...?